# In Input fields replace more spaces with one space in php using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

In input field replace more than one space with one space after save button. 
string = string.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ');
It worked but it does not saved permanently into that value. I need to save permanently with one space only

Comment: Please show us your code

Comment: Is this JavaScript or PHP question? Why the jQuery tag for string manipulation with regular expressions?

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that `replace` doesn't mutate the string, but rather returns a new one.

```js
const original = 'this  has   double    spaces';
const singleSpaced = original.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ');
console.log('Original: ' + original)
console.log('Single-spaced: ' + singleSpaced);
```

Comment: Then what i have to do for permanent save of that field with single space

Comment: It's saved in variable `singleSpaced`. Just save that one into your database (or wherever you're saving data) instead of the `original` one.